# How do I modify SQL table so that it includes a column with TRUE/FALSE values?

Tags: android, sql

I'm trying to modify an SQL table to have true false values. I am using type BIT for a 1 or 0. I tried to alter the table but it does not seems to be working properly. The column index is -1.

For my sqlitehelper class, I tried using this for my onupgrade method:

```
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {

        Log.d(TAG,"inner onupgrade called");
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " 
                + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableMetaData.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TableMetaData.TABLE_NAME 
                + " ADD COLUMN " + TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED + " BIT DEFAULT 0"
                + ";");
           //onCreate(db);
    }
```

When I try to read the column later in my app I get an error and I find that the column index is -1. Am I modifying the table correctly?

Here is the error I get from the logcat:

```
03-27 17:48:37.111: E/CursorWindow(2884): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 5
03-27 17:48:37.111: D/AndroidRuntime(2884): Shutting down VM
03-27 17:48:37.111: W/dalvikvm(2884): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
03-27 17:48:37.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 17:48:37.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2884): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
03-27 17:48:37.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2884):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
03-27 17:48:37.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2884):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
03-27 17:48:37.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2884):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contentprovider I did not add the column in the hashmap.

```
public class ThoughtProvider extends ContentProvider
{
//Logging helper tag. No significance to providers.
private static final String TAG = "ThoughtProvider";

//Projection maps are similar to "as" construct
//in an sql statement where by you can rename the 
//columns.
private static HashMap<String, String> sBooksProjectionMap;
static 
{
    sBooksProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(TableMetaData._ID, 
                                TableMetaData._ID);

//I needed to add:


    sBooksProjectionMap.put(TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED,
                            TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, there is not BIT datatype in sqlite3 http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I changed to type to INTEGER and the same thing seems to be happening.